# How can i add tabs in iOS on a particular screen?

Tags: ios

I am building an app where I need to add a TabBarController on a particular screen, Lets assume maybe on second or third screen.

I have gone through several blogs but everyone says UITabBarController can be added as an initial view controller only.

But I want it for some few screens only. How can I accomplish it?

Need guidance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "you shouldn't."

From the Human Interface Guidelines:

"In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the app level. A tab bar is well suited for use in the main app view because it’s a good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to several peer information categories or modes at one time.

**Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current screen** or app mode. If you need to provide controls, including a control that displays a modal view, use a toolbar instead (for usage guidelines, see Toolbar). "